# Import "numpy" could not be resolved; ipynb in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, jupyter

Im in trouble with using umpy module in ipynb(jupyter notebook) file in vscode, it doesn't work only in ipynb file. If I make new .py file and import modules, no error comes out.

Could anybody tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the kernel version in the upper right corner, and then select the correct kernel (The one with ***numpy*** installed).

[image]

Comment: Glad my answer was helpful to you, you can change the status of the answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: oh i forgot it sry thanks again :)